# Axios , express-session , cors response.headers["set-cookie"] returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, sockets

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cors from "cors";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import session from "express-session";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import MongoStore from "connect-mongo";
import http from "http";
dotenv.config({ path: "./config.env" });
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
import { Server } from "socket.io";

const DB = process.env.DATABASE_STRING.replace(
  "<password>",
  process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD
);

mongoose
  .connect(DB)
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`database connection was successfull ! :) \n`);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(
      `error - ${error} happened while attempting to connect to database :) \n `
    );
  });
console.log(process.env.SECRET);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:5173",
    credentials: true,
  })
);

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: MongoStore.create({
      mongoUrl: DB,
      collection: "sessions", // Collection name to store sessions
      ttl: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60,
      cookie: { secure: false },
    }),
    cookie: {
      path: "/",
      secure: false,
      maxAge: 4 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    },
  })
);

app.get("/initialize-session", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const sess = req.session;
    console.log(req.session, " --- req.session --- \n");
    res.status(200).json({ message: "session init" });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: `session init fail ${error}` });
  }
});

app.get("/chats/initiateChat", (req, res) => {
  console.log(`req recieved to chats/initiateChat endpoint`);
});

app.get("/findPartner", (req, res) => {
  /* out of all sockets availabe select one randomly... */

  console.log(` get request received to findPartner endpoint \n`);

  res.status(200).json({ message: "success" });
});

app.get("/authenticate-user", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.headers.cookie, " --cookie--- ");
  res.status(200).json({ status: "success" });
});

const activeUsers = {};

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: process.env.FRONTEND_ORIGIN,
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true,
  },
});

io.on("connection", async (socket) => {
  console.log(socket.id, " ---socket user connected  \n");

  socket.on("chat-message", (msg) => {
    console.log("message: " + JSON.stringify(msg));
  });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT;

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(` server listening on ${PORT}`);
});



import React, { useState } from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import axios from "axios";

export const ChatPage = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  const handleMessageTransmission = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const socket = io("http://localhost:6040", {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      withCredentials: true,
    });

    if (message) {
      console.log(`this is the message ${message}`);
      const uniqueId = uuidv4();
      socket.emit("chat-message", { message });
    }

    axios
      .get("http://localhost:6040/authenticate-user", {
        withCredentials: true,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log( response.headers['set-cookie'] , " cookie ")
      })
      .catch((error) => {});
  };

  return (
    <div
      id="Chat-Page-Main"
      className="w-screen h-screen bg-bg3 flex flex-col "
    >
      <div id="Chat-Container" className="flex flex-col w-full flex-grow"> </div>
      <form
        id="Send-Message-form"
        className="flex flex-row justify-evenly p-2 sm:p-4 h-24 bg-bg2"
        method="post"
        onSubmit={(e) => handleMessageTransmission(e)}
      >
        <div
          id="Profile-Image-Wrapper"
          className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center "
        >
          <img
            src="/avatardummy.png"
            id="Profile-Dummy"
            className="rounded-full w-12 h-12"
          />
        </div>

        <input
          type="text"
          className="flex-grow rounded-md m-2"
          placeholder="Hi..."
          onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button
          id="Send-Message-Button"
          className=" rounded-md shadow-md text-center"
        >
          Send
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

So I am trying to couple my message payload with sessionId , but i am not not able to do that because when i am trying to access document.cookie it always returns undefined , so then i decided to access cookie from the response.headers and then manually add it to the message payload inside of socket now response.headers['set-cookie'] always returns undefined

Comment: And what do you see if you log the entire `response.headers` object?

Comment: @JamieWeston i cant see a Set-Cookie header in the response headers

Comment: On which side? If it's in the browser, you're explicitly denied from reading the Set-Cookie header and will have to trust the browser to store it for you - it cannot be read programmatically by code running in the browser page. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie

Comment: I cannot see the Set-Cookie field in the response headers in Network Tab developer tools is what i meant to say, yes when i was attempting to access connect.sid from document.cookie it kept returning nothing

Comment: @JamieWeston now i am able to see the Set-Cookie header its being stored in the browser too but cant access it either by request.headers["set-cookie"] when the component renders  nor can i can access it with document.cookie ( which i read somewhere is expected and not a bug)

Comment: This is normal. You *cannot* access anything related to the Set-Cookie header programmatically. The browser sees the header, sets the cookie, and removes the header, all before your code sees the response. Now that the cookie is set, it will be included in all future requests made by your code.

Comment: You should also be familiar with the attributes that can be specified when setting a cookie. `express-session` will set the HttpOnly (which prevents you accessing the cookie via `document.cookie` and Secure (which means the cookie is only shared on HTTPS requests) flags.

Comment: @JamieWeston so req.headers["set-cookie"] and document.cookie returning undefined is a feature not a bug?

Comment: Correct. They are security features, designed to stop malicious code gaining access to things that only the communications between your site and the service should know.